# Convert PDF to JPEG

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to create a process of converting base64 of pdf to base64 of jpeg image. The problem that I have is if pdf is scanned with less than 600dpi, image is not rendered correctly, it is white image without any content in it.

This is my code:

```
public String convertPDFtoJPEG(byte[] pdfData) {
    try {
      PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfData);
      PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

      for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < document.getNumberOfPages(); pageIndex++) {
        BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageIndex, 300);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "JPEG", baos);

        baos.flush();

        String base64JPEG = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());

        baos.close();
      }

      document.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return base64JPEG;

  }

 public byte[] readBase64FromFile(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        baos.write(line.getBytes());
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return Base64.getDecoder().decode(baos.toByteArray());
  }
```

This is how I'm calling this methods:

```
String filepath = "path:\\to\\file.txt"
byte[] pdfData = readBase64FromFile(filePath);

convertPDFtoJPEG(pdfData);
```

In file.txt is base64 of pdf.

Comment: Please check all the intermediate steps:
- is pdfData really a PDF? Save it into a file to check
- is the rendered image really an image? Save it into a file to check
Also look at log messages, and make sure you have the latest PDFBox
version with all the dependencies (jbig2 decoder)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr. Checked all of this. Version of PDFBox is 2.0.28. What I additionaly  tested is that I scanned document with 2 different scanners in 300 and 600dpi. On first scanner is problem above, on second scanner converting is good for both dpi. I think that dpi shouldn't be even important at all. Might be a problem with scanner? Maybe scanner doesn't send some metadata?

Comment: You wrote "Checked all of this" but you're not telling what worked. Are both (I understand that this is about 2 different ones) PDFs ok when saved? Are the JPEGs ok when saved directly? I want to find out whether this base64 stuff plays a role here or not. Try to display the files with PDFDebugger.

Comment: @newhere Could we help you and did you solve your problem? It is custom on SO to "follow-up" you question and continue in the conversion...

Comment: @TilmanHausherr. PDF's are ok when saved. What do you mean by JPEG's saved directly?

Comment: Save them as file and not base64. This way you'll know whether the JPEG was ok before it was converted to base64. If the directly saved JPEG is not ok then share it for analysis. I'm lazy (sorry!) so I didn't bother to understand your code and first wanted to know whether the core part (PDF rendering) works or not. Oh, I just looked at your code and you seem to have TWO `base64JPEG` variables (one inner, one global that is returned), or this isn't your actual code, i.e. you messed up something when editing.

Comment: No, JPEG is not ok when saved as file. If it helps, I've converted bytes to string to see headers of both PDF's, one that working and one that not working.  One that working have some hash after stream, one that not working, doesn't have anything. It's like that doesn't have any content, but it is valid PDF.

Comment: Then share this PDF.

Comment: https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20230531ZC9SUjO8

Comment: Make sure the JPX and JBIG2 decoder are in your classpath. https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html  There is a log message if you don't (did you switch off the log messages?). The file renders properly for me.

Comment: implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.28'
  implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:jbig2-imageio:3.0.4'

This are my dependencies

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency> and <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency> and find out why your logging is disabled.

Comment: Those dependecies solved problem. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks I've added it as answer. Note that the version number is different from the comment. In the comment I copy-pasted from github readme, which was outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, make sure you have the dependencies for JPX and JBIG2 image formats:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I also recommend using the [twelvemonkeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) library for TIFF and JPEG.

Comment: Ah ok the libs were missing - good catch!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You are not decoding the base64 data correctly. You read the file line by line and convert (each line) to bytes. Then at the end you pass the whole thing to the Base64 decoder converting it back to string. You should change the method to:

   ```
   public static byte[] readBase64FromFile(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    StringBuilder base64StringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            base64StringBuilder.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64StringBuilder.toString());
   }
   ```

   Or read the whole thing as a binary:

   ```
   public static byte[] readBinaryFromFile(String filePath) {

    Path path2Pdf = Paths.get(filePath);

    byte[] pdf = new byte[]{};
    try {
        pdf = Files.readAllBytes(path2Pdf);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Base64.getDecoder().decode(pdf);
   }
   ```
2. Your `convertPDFtoJPEG` method doesn't make sense. You are reading the whole file but only return the last page (which might even be a white page). You should return a list of base64 jpeg pages:

   ```
   public static List<String> convertPDFtoJPEG(byte[] pdfData) {
    List<String> listOfBase64Images = new ArrayList<>();

    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfData)){
        PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

        for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < document.getNumberOfPages(); pageIndex++) {
            BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageIndex, 300);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "JPEG", baos);
            listOfBase64Images.add(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray()));
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listOfBase64Images;
   ```

   }

And fyi: calling close() and flush() on a `ByteArrayOutputStream` doesn't do anything.

Comment: When passing byte from readBinaryFromFile() to PDFDocument.load it says End-of-File. I tried your modified readBase64FromFile() and when returning value, it says Illegal base64 character 5b.

Comment: @newhere In the readBinaryFromFile the base64 decoding was missing. I added it. So try again. Also in the other method I was incorrectly calling `line.getBytes()` - which I corrected. Please try again...